# Why are there only two 496-dim. gauge groups $E_8\times E_8$ and $SO(32)$ allowed in string theory? Why not $E_8\times U(1)^{248}$ or $U(1)^{496}$?

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-anomalies

While constructing anomaly-free string theories with $\mathcal N=1$ supersymmetry (16 supercharges constituting a Majorana-Weyl spinor), we learn that the gauge group must be 496-dimensional in order to cancel some terms (like $\mathrm{tr} R^6$) in the anomaly polynomial, which is a 12-form characteristic class. There are also some other more involved conditions that I will not reproduce here.

This is satisfied by the groups $E_8\times E_8$ and $\mathrm{SO}(32)$, for which the corresponding heterotic string theories are very well-known. However, the groups $E_8\times U(1)^{248}$ and $U(1)^{496}$ are also anomaly-free since they satisfy the above constraints (at least at face level), but there is no string theory with these gauge groups!

Why is this the case? Have there been any modern developments in a rigorous proof of their absence?

Comment: You appear to have another account here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/u/307576. If this is you, you can [merge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) the accounts.

Comment: I am not having access to the email address that I used for the previous account. If the administrators could let me know if there is any other process I am happy to hear it

Comment: @Tevatron5 see https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1525, [String universality: there's no $U(1)^{496}$ theory](https://motls.blogspot.com/2010/07/string-universality-theres-no-u1496.html) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilteJ-fBd4k&t=3252s

Comment: @Tevatron5: Try write the SE team anyway. They might become convinced that you own both accounts from e.g. your log-in history even if you have lost access.